# Page crashes(reading properties of undefined) in React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

In my project I'm using redux toolkit and react router v6. I have invoices list with 'View' button and when it's clicked it should open page with description about invoice. Also i have add invoice feature. When invoice added and I click on 'View' button page crashes and the error in console say:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invoice_num')

[image: Error here]

And the same happens if i click on existing item and reload the page. It says the error occured in InvoiceItem.js page.

Now the code. ***InvoiceItem.js***

```
import React from "react";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import InvoiceItemDescription from "../Invoice/InvoiceItemDescription";

import { INVOICES_LIST } from "./InvoicesList";

const InvoiceItem = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  const invoice = INVOICES_LIST.find(
    (invoice) => invoice.id === params.invoiceId
  );

  return (
    <InvoiceItemDescription
      invoiceNumber={invoice.invoice_num}
      status={invoice.status}
      order_date={invoice.order_date}
      bill_from={invoice.bill_from}
      bill_from_address={invoice.bill_from_address}
      bill_from_email={invoice.bill_from_email}
      bill_from_fax={invoice.bill_from_fax}
      bill_from_phone={invoice.bill_from_phone}
      bill_to={invoice.bill_to}
      bill_to_address={invoice.bill_to_address}
      bill_to_email={invoice.bill_to_email}
      bill_to_fax={invoice.bill_to_fax}
      bill_to_phone={invoice.bill_to_phone}
      item_name={invoice.ITEMS.item_name}
      unit_costs={invoice.ITEMS.unit_costs}
      unit={invoice.ITEMS.unit}
      price={invoice.ITEMS.price}
    />
  );
};

export default InvoiceItem;
```

***InvoiceItemDescription.js*** file

```
import React from "react";

import Wrapper from "../../UI/Wrapper";
import Footer from "../../UI/Footer";

import classes from "./InvoiceItemDescription.module.css";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const InvoiceItemDescription = (props) => {
  let counter = 1;

  return (
    <Wrapper isShrinked={props.isShrinked}>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes["content-wrapper"]}>
          <div className={classes["main-wrapper"]}>
            <div className={classes["upper-buttons"]}>
              <div className={classes["upper-buttons-wrapper"]}>
                <Link to="/invoices">
                  <button type="button" className={classes["go-to-invoices"]}>
                    Go To Invoices
                  </button>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/invoices/edit-invoice">
                  <button type="button" className={classes["edit-invoice"]}>
                    Edit Invoice
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.content}>
              <div className={classes["invoice-info"]}>
                <div className={classes.info}>
                  <h3>Invoice Info</h3>
                  <span>{props.invoiceNumber}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.order}>
                  <p>
                    <span className={classes["order-status"]}>
                      Order Status:
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.status}>{props.status}</span>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span className={classes["order-date"]}>Order Date:</span>
                    <span className={classes.date}>{props.order_date}</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.bills}>
                <div className={classes["bill-from"]}>
                  <h3>Bill From</h3>
                  <div>
                    <p className={classes["bill-from-info"]}>
                      <span className={classes.name}>{props.bill_from}</span>
                      <span className={classes.email}>
                        {props.bill_from_email}
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br> {props.bill_from_address}
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br> {props.bill_from_phone}
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes["bill-to"]}>
                  <h3>Bill To</h3>
                  <p className={classes["bill-to-info"]}>
                    <span className={classes.name}>{props.bill_to}</span>
                    <span className={classes.email}>
                      {props.bill_to_email} <br></br>
                      <br></br> {props.bill_to_address} <br></br>
                      <br></br>
                      <br></br>
                      {props.bill_to_fax} <br></br> {props.bill_to_phone}
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.table}>
                <table>
                  <colgroup>
                    <col className={classes.col1}></col>
                    <col className={classes.col2}></col>
                    <col className={classes.col3}></col>
                    <col className={classes.col4}></col>
                    <col className={classes.col5}></col>
                  </colgroup>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td>#</td>
                      <td>Item Name</td>
                      <td>Unit Costs</td>
                      <td>Unit</td>
                      <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{counter++}</td>
                      <td>{props.item_name}</td>
                      <td>{props.unit_costs}</td>
                      <td>{props.unit}</td>
                      <td>{props.price}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.total}>
                <p>
                  Sub-total:
                  <span>$13300</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Vat:
                  <span>$13300</span>
                </p>
                <h3>
                  Grand Total:
                  <span>$14630</span>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes["lower-btn"]}>
              <button type="button">Send Invoice</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default InvoiceItemDescription;
```

And ***Invoice.js*** file

```
import React from "react";

import classes from "./Invoice.module.css";

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { invoiceActions } from "../../store/invoice-slice";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Invoice = (props) => {
  const { id, invoice_num, bill_from, bill_to, status } = props.invoiceItem;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const removeInvoiceItem = () => {
    dispatch(invoiceActions.removeInvoice(id));
  };

  return (
    <tr className={classes.height}>
      <td>
        <span className={classes.checkbox}>
          <input type="checkbox"></input>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>{invoice_num}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>{bill_from}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>{bill_to}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>14300</span>
        {/* This should be a dynamic value later */}
      </td>
      <td>
        <span
          className={`${
            status === "Pending" ? classes["status-pending"] : ""
          } ${status === "Delivered" ? classes["status-delivered"] : ""} ${
            status === "Shipped" ? classes["status-shipped"] : ""
          }`}
        >
          {status}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div className={classes.buttons}>
          <Link to={`/invoices/invoice-description/${id}`}>
            <button className={classes["view-btn"]}>View</button>
          </Link>
          <button className={classes["delete-btn"]} onClick={removeInvoiceItem}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default Invoice;
```

I have no idea what can cause the crash of the page. Can someone help me with this, please?

P.S. here is my github repo(it's my PET project) - https://github.com/stepan-slyvka/test-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the `INVOICES_LIST` test invoice data exported from `src/components/Pages/Invoice/InvoicesList.js` you are creating randomly generated `id` properties. When the page reloads, the entire app reloads, `INVOICES_LIST` is exported with all new `id` properties. The `id` that is read from the URL path is no longer valid and `InvoiceItem` can't render an `invoice` object that is undefined.

```
export const INVOICES_LIST = [
  {
    id: Math.random().toString(), // <-- random each time app loads
    ...
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toString(), // <-- random each time app loads
    ...
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toString(), // <-- random each time app loads
    ...
  },
];
```

You really want GUIDs to be stable, and more determinant and guaranteed for uniqueness, so don't use `Math.random` to create them, use something more like [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) if you need to generate unique ids.

To resolve your specific issue the fix is to just hardcode a unique `id` value. Even just complete gibberish, so long as it uniquely identifies an object, is sufficient (*for testing*).

Example:

```
export const INVOICES_LIST = [
  {
    id: '09u34otiuhnrfgp9ioj45',
    ...
  },
  {
    id: '234098ujh43gikoljaerpgiojaerg',
    ...
  },
  {
    id: '0934tpinr-9ujw3ensdsf',
    ...
  },
];
```

In the `InvoiceItem` component that is searching the `INVOICES_LIST` array keep in mind that `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns `undefined` when no match is found. The UI should handle this. Conditionally render the `InvoiceItemDescription` only if there is a found `invoice`.

Example:

```
const InvoiceItem = () => {
  const { invoiceId } = useParams();

  const invoice = INVOICES_LIST.find((invoice) => invoice.id === invoiceId);

  return invoice ? (
    <InvoiceItemDescription
      invoice_num={invoice.invoice_num}
      status={invoice.status}
      order_date={invoice.order_date}
      bill_from={invoice.bill_from}
      bill_from_address={invoice.bill_from_address}
      bill_from_email={invoice.bill_from_email}
      bill_from_fax={invoice.bill_from_fax}
      bill_from_phone={invoice.bill_from_phone}
      bill_to={invoice.bill_to}
      bill_to_address={invoice.bill_to_address}
      bill_to_email={invoice.bill_to_email}
      bill_to_fax={invoice.bill_to_fax}
      bill_to_phone={invoice.bill_to_phone}
      item_name={invoice.ITEMS.item_name}
      unit_costs={invoice.ITEMS.unit_costs}
      unit={invoice.ITEMS.unit}
      price={invoice.ITEMS.price}
    />
  ) : (
    <div>No Invoices Found.</div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit page-crashesreading-properties-of-undefined-in-react-js]

Comment: Okay. So as i understood i have to hardcode id's for my static invoices(INVOICES_LIST) and for new invoice that is created by user manually, i have to use uuid extention, right? Or i should use uuid for both? Because now i've changed everything as you mentioned, but it renders <div>No Invoices Found</div> when i try to View newly created invoice.

Comment: @StepanSlyvka Yes, for your static "test data" you want static ids that are the same each time the app loads. For the real data you should generate the id property when the data is created and the id should never change from that point forward, wherever you are storing it. If you've done as I've done in my answer here it should work for you. Can you create a codesandbox demo of your own that reproduces the issue you are still facing that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReeseSure, in the next answer I'll post codesandbox demo.

Comment: @StepanSlyvka The code in *your* codesandbox appears to load invoices just fine. Navigating to `"/invoices"` from the sidebar loads the three invoices and clicking any of their "View" buttons correctly navigates to their details page and the invoice renders. Is there something I'm missing or not reproducing the same way you are? What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @StepanSlyvka I see now what the issue is, it's when you add a new invoice, the `InvoiceItem` page uses the `INVOICES_LIST` array instead of the `state.invoice.invoices` array from the redux state. You'll want to select this state from your redux store and use *this* array to find the corresponding `invoice` object. See this codesandbox [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-crashesreading-properties-of-undefined-in-react-js-quyph7). After adding a new invoice you can view the details. This OFC only works until the page is refreshed and the app state resets. You'll need to persist the state.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine! Thank you very much! I've solved my issue. And about persisting the state. I'm going to connect this app to firebase, so refreshing the page won't crash newly created invoice anymore. P.S. It's so good when some1 who's got more practice and knowledge can share with you and help you with solving your issues.

Answer (score 0):

So, issue is fixed and to conclude, maybe someone is facing the same problem, I'll write a few words.

Firstly, when you have static data like I had(3 invoices which renders each time page loads) - hardcode your id's.

Secondly, for newly created items use stable id's(example - uuid) and store it somewhere(for example in local storage).

Thirdly, if page crashes or something renders wrong - check your state! In my case issue was in InvoiceItem.js file where i was trying to render INVOICES_LIST instead of selecting my state with `const invoices = useSelector((state) => state.invoice.invoices)`

Hope, this helps someone like me - novice in redux :)

P.S. final code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-crashesreading-properties-of-undefined-in-react-js-quyph7)